# Building a search bar

Tags: html, search

I'm currently creating a website for a school project, and I would like to add a search bar in which we can look for a word on the website. It would work like a traditional Ctrl+F (Command+F) but for every html file on the website, and then present the result either on a pop-up or on a different page.

I believe this requires a specific software, but I don't know which one, and I'm pretty sure I don't know how to use it.

Thanks for any insight on how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You have a plenty of options.  The particular choice will depend on your site specifics (is the content static or dynamic etc.).  Anyway you will need to build a search index. I suggest to use something almost ready to go.  See elasticsearch and a crawler for it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to use [Google Custom Search](https://www.google.com/cse/) if the website will be online.

Another option would be to build or use an existing php search script. In this case your webhoster must support php. for static webpages this is not the best option, as the script has to search through all files everytime you search something.

It will be a lot easier if you use a CMS (Content Management System) to build your site, they usually have the Search-functionality included or as an addon.

For more information also checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752806/need-to-add-a-search-to-static-html-site)